# Saying a word in a way that describes its meaning

Tags: pronunciation, emphasis

Is there an English term that is used when one says a word in a way that somewhat describes what it means?

For example "Peter was really ANGRY at you Damien!"...

Here, large emphasis would be placed on the word Angry, it would be said in loud, bold tone, face crumpled and eyebrows cross.

---

Also is there a term that means when the name of a font is said, for example the font "Joker" - that the way one says the font name emphasises what the font is visually like?

For example with the "Joker" font, I would say it with light tone bouncing on the syllables: "Jo-Kerrrre".

Comment: I suggest that you post the two questions separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For the spoken word, in linguistics, **intonation** is variation of spoken pitch that is
>   not used to distinguish words; instead it is used for a range of
>   functions such as indicating the attitudes and emotions of the speaker
>   ... focusing attention on important elements of the spoken message ...

{[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intonation_%28linguistics%29)}

This obviously covers the required sense, but perhaps isn't specific enough (shouting 'Quiet!' would certainly focus attention on the demand).

'Self-referential' may be deemed more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

**"You don't have to act out your words. Just saying you're mad at me is enough."**

Comment: haha cute answer... but not the one I'm after :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Drew I thought I understood the question. And if I thought I understood, it would make no sense to critique or request clarification. I've posted as an answer what I thought would be the phrase the O.P. was looking for. Also, I know what comments are for and I know the rules at EL&U, written or unwritten. Thanks for reminding me anyway.